# MySQL query's suceed in PHPMyAdmin but not in the PHP Script itself

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Just while playing around with Querying in PHP i ran into some trouble. The title of this post explains the problem. When i run a query in PHPMyAdmin the results will be different from the results i get in the PHP program itself. Here is the code i am using. Sorry if it looks a little odd i've been cutting and pasting things all over the place in a frantic attempt to get it working.

```
$connect = array('username'=>'root', 'host'=>'127.0.0.1', 'password'=>'');
$link = mysql_connect($connect['host'], $connect['username'], $connect['password']) or die('Error creating link: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('testing_pages', $link) or die('Error connecting to database: ' . mysql_error());
$sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `names`";
$query = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die('Query Failed! Check error:<br/><br/>' . mysql_error());
$query_2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$query = $query_2;
$loop = count($query);
$count = 0;

while($count <= $loop) {
    echo $query[$count] . '<br/>';
    $count++;
    }
```

see, what im trying to get it to do is read all the names, pop it into an array, then print them out with a while loop. But it only seems to return 1 result and thats the first name in the databse. but when i run the EXACT query through phpmyadmin it will return every name in the database... Another odd thing, when using the 'count' function to get the number of values in the array is claims that there are 3 values, but during the loop it just prints out the first name, then for the second two it returns an 'Undefined index'.

Hope i dont seem like a noob right now... And i hope i explained everything well. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Why do you overwrite `$query` with the value of `$query_2`?

Comment: 1) You need to stop using deprecated `mysql` extension. 2) There is nothing wrong with your query, you seem to have a misunderstanding on how to fetch the results of the result set. 3) You need to fetch database results in a loop, not a single `mysql_fetch_array()`.  Basically you are only getting a single value now.

Comment: Yes i see. But, I am confused. Why is mysql deprecated? Why is it being sort of 'gotten rid of'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` fetches one row in the form of an array. [Here are the docs](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

And pay attention to that big warning message at the top of the page when you read the docs...

Comment: SO i guess i shouldnt be using mysql_fetch_array?

Comment: wait but this confuses me, why are all these functions being gotten rid of?

Comment: I know there are some useful features that the `mysql_` functions do not support, but beyond that I don't know. In any case, those functions will be going away, so you shouldn't use them because servers in the future will not have them.